# Listen before talk (LBT) of SI4463

Tags: rf, wireless

SI4463 can  listen before talk (LBT) . I found this function in  [29 page of datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/Si4463-61-60-C.pdf) . I think I can use LBT to make a band scanner like [this](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Nrf24L01-Poor+Man%27s+2.4+GHz+Scanner) . But there is not any example to show how to do.

Only arduino I am familiar to , and I think I should use [SPI library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI) to send commend to SI4463 and recieve data, for example, SPI.tansfer(commend). But I don't know which commend can do this .  In fact,  I just can use [RH_RF24.h](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/classRH__RF24.html) to control SI4463. But there is not suitable function to make a scanner. The RSSI of  [RH_RF24.h](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/classRH__RF24.html) is the RSSI of the last received message. It can't be used to LBT.

Sorry for my poor English. If there is any problem about my question , please tell me.

Thanks.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RH_RF24.h>

// Singleton instance of the radio driver
RH_RF24 rf24;


uint8_t Recieve_Data[20];

uint8_t receive_buffer[RH_RF24_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
uint8_t receive_buffer_length = sizeof(receive_buffer);

uint8_t Rssi;

unsigned long Micro_Time;

uint8_t status[8];
uint8_t buf[RH_RF24_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if (!rf24.init())
    Serial.println("init failed");
  // Defaults after init are 434.0MHz, modulation GFSK_Rb5Fd10, power 0x10
   while(!rf24.setFrequency(443));
  rf24.setModemConfig(rf24.GFSK_Rb50Fd100);  //设置成GFSK_Rb50Fd100
}


void loop()
{
  rf24.setModeRx();
  delay(100);
  rf24.setModeIdle();
  rf24.command(RH_RF24_CMD_GET_INT_STATUS, NULL, 0, status, sizeof(status));
  Serial.print("Id   ");
  for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
  {
    Serial.print((uint8_t)status[i]);
    Serial.print("   ");
  }
  Serial.println();
  /*
    if (status[2])
    {
      uint8_t modem_status[6];
      rf24.command(RH_RF24_CMD_GET_MODEM_STATUS, NULL, 0, modem_status, sizeof(modem_status));
      delay(100);
      for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
      {
        Serial.print(modem_status[i]);
        Serial.print("   ");
      }
      Serial.println();
    }
  */
  delay(400);
}
```

Comment: Please note that the term "LBT" is often used to scan the home channel before sending, and if RSSI is found there, wait. This is of course not the same thing as an intelligent band scanner which looks for available frequencies. As for whether Silabs actually supports intelligent band scanning or not, I don't know.

Comment: @Lundin  I need not to find available frequency. Just want to know the RSSI of different frequencies. But the RH_RF24.h only give RSSI of the last received message. So , I can't scan . But if I have a way to listen before talk . I can know the RSSI without receive any message. So, I want to know how to realize  LBT. In fact ,really what I need is not LBT , is RSSI without receive any message. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet says: "The latched RSSI values are cleared when entering RX mode so they may be read after the packet is received... *or after dropping back to standby mode*". This suggests use of the following functions from the RadioHead library:

```
void RH_RF24::setModeRx()
void RH_RF24::setModeIdle()
bool RH_RF24::get_properties(...)
```

Comment: Could you give a code ? I fail to use get_properties...

Comment: Make a question with the code you have, and explain how it fails. Then we may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, I have add my code in above.  The result is like before. If there is another Si4463 work at same frequence and GFSK_Rb50Fd100, the RSSI is not zero. Otherwise , RSSI is zero , although, there is a Si4463 work at same frequence with different GFSK. I don't know how to use bool RH_RF24::get_properties(...) to get RSSI. So, I use rf24.command(), because I found how to use it to get RSSI in header file.